# Why does google reject my web extension with the reference Yellow Magnesium

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json, unhandled-promise-rejection

This is my first time uploading an extension and it got rejected. In the email i got it said

`Spam and placement in the Store Details  Violation reference ID: Yellow Magnesium Violation: The item does not work. How to rectify: Ensure that your item is working properly and resubmit it. Relevant section of the programme policy: Extensions with broken functionality – such as dead sites or non-functioning features – are not allowed.`

I have been researching a lot and I still don't what the problem is. I think it may be the manifest so here it is(i have changed it 3 times)

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Germy Drop",
"description": "Avoid the Germs",
"version": "1.0.0.0",
"background": {
    "launch": {
        "local_path": "index.html"
    }
},
"icons": {
    "16": "playstore-icon16.png",
    "128": "playstore-icon128.png"

}
```

}

this extension is a game extension so you can click the icon on the top right of the screen and the game will launch. sorry for that lack of information i am just new to all of this. thanks

Comment: `launch` key means it's NOT an extension but an ancient hosted app, which are deprecated and are not allowed anymore.

Comment: i am a bit confused what can i use instead of `launch` ( i am using the unity engine and sorry for the long respond time)

Comment: See [the overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview). You need a background script and an `action` API click handler.

Comment: I had fixed everything in the manifest but it still is getting rejected. ) :

Comment: i have uploaded the same game to google play and i found the violation is Relevant section of the programme policy: Extensions with broken functionality – such as dead sites or non-functioning features – are not allowed.

Comment: i am going to try this web https://www.indiehackers.com/post/extension-re-reviewed-and-approved-87c3f01e07